# How do I match a word within the first 20 words of a text in Regex php?

Tags: regex

I looked at other similar questions and they did not work in a regex test.

Please post formula that works.  Thanks

Comment: Maybe you'll want to post also what you've tried in order to achieve that. Also expected behaviour usually helps. If you have any doubts whether you're having a good approach when asking a question have a look at this list https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: I tried:  ^(?:\w+\s*){0,20}(food).  I wanted to match "food" within the first 20 words of a text but it doesnt work.

Comment: why do you say it doesn't work? I've just tested it and it works

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/ekxyzD/1

Comment: Try `^\s*(?:\w+\s+){0,20}food`

Comment: Ok.  Please help with this: https://regex101.com/r/OEoLaD/1. Why wont it match other words too?

Comment: @ike Try omitting the `^` at the beginning

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Why did ^ prevent it from matching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is almost correct but needs little modifications. Instead of this,

```
 ^(?:\w+\s*){0,20}(food)
```

you should use this,

```
^(\w+\W+){0,19}food
```

In your regex, you wrote `{0,20}` which will actually already count 20 words and your food becomes 21st word which should then not match as you wrote in your post that match word `food` withing first 20 words. So, to be precise, you should correct it to {0,19}.

Second problem is, as you have written `\w+\s*` in your regex, so if your line contains say anything other than word character or whitespace (may be a punctuation or period or exclamation etc.), then this regex will not match. To cover any other character you should safely use `\W` character which will match any non-word character.

And as someone said in comments, you should remove `^` from start of regex to make it match, but then it may match but then it won't be from the first twenty words and instead will find any such pattern in the middle of text which will be incorrect. So retain caret `^` (aka start anchor) for matching only from the first 20 characters.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5ZQHq4/1)**

Let me know if this is what you've been looking for.